# Moto G won't detect sim card

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, sim-card, motorola-moto-g

I recently bought a 8 GB Moto G Unlocked. When I try putting in the sim card into the phone the phone doesn't seem to detect the sim.

Any solution?

Comment: [nachouy44](http://android.stackexchange.com/users/68669/nachouy44) asks for clarification (but lacks the rep to post a comment himself): *Could it be the SIM is broken?* → you might verify that with a different device. Could also be an issue with the contacts not connecting correctly.

Comment: This model is a lemon. I bought one this past winter. After about 6 months it stopped recognizing SIM on daily basis. I sent it in for replacement. Replacement worked for about 8 days. I guess I'd be better of spending my money for a brand name phone.

Comment: Do you know which GSM version that your model is? Certain devices are only compatable with certain carriers. I know that the US-GM is compatable with only AT&T and T-Mobile bands, while the Iternational GM is compatible with AT&T(in America).